# How to make elements appear one by one using css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to make elements appear one by one using css animation (jQuery), I try to make it seems like a wave but I can only show all elements at once, so I would appreciate a lot if you help me

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".wave").each(function() {
    var position = $(this).offset().top;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (position < winTop + 650) {
      $(this).addClass("slide-wave");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wave {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slide-wave {
  animation: slide-one .4s;
  visibility: visible;
}
@keyframes slide-one {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(80%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wave"></div>
<div class="wave"></div>
<div class="wave"></div>
<div class="wave"></div>
```

Comment: Wait a minute... you want to animate them on scroll? ... one by one? huh?

Comment: maybe you should add some elements and styles to see if it really does not work ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXEKjE

Comment: why are you downvoting here guys ? It seems that he just doesn't understands what minimal content or styling is required for the script to take effect :)

Comment: yes, during scrolling they have to appear on one line but with delay

Comment: I'd do this with a lazy load plugin which lazy loads elements as well and then add the css classes.

Comment: your script works, but it needs content and jQuery library .... so do you have a full example that shows it does not work ? this script works pulling them up, not side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just written some similar code to flash or pop individual characters in a string. I'm not offering anything specific to your code but more the principle or method I used to apply animations to a group of elements.

This is along similar lines - it might be of use, first I gave each element of my string an individual, sequential ID - sort of like an array:

```
<p id="char-0">S</p>
<p id="char-1">t</p>
<p id="char-2">r</p>
<p id="char-3">i</p>
<p id="char-4">n</p>
<p id="char-5">g</p>
```

I actually wrote a function that takes a string as an argument and generates these <p> tags with the sequential ID's. the next thing I did was write a recursive function that iterates through all elements, something like this:

```
function popElements(
    strElID,     // Element ID prefix string
    intStart,    // Start element
    intEnd,      // End element
    objTo,       // Animate from current state to this...
    objFrom,     // ...animate from objTo to this.
    intDuration, // duration for the animations.
    strEasing,   // For animate
    intTimeout   // Interval between recursive calls
) {

    var e = intStart;   // intFrom needs to be increased/decreased for next
                        // call, record it here.
    var f;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Use the .length property to check for the existence of
        // this element, if we call:
        //
        //    popElements(
        //        "char-",
        //        0,
        //        10,
        //        { "opacity": "0.00" },
        //        { "opacity": "0.99" },
        //        500,
        //        "linear",
        //        100
        //    )
        // We will apply the animations to all char-*n* and return when
        // char-*n* isn't found
        if ($("#" + strElID + e.toString()).length == 0)
            return;

        // We need to remember the value of e because it points to the
        // current element being animated, but we need to increase/decrease
        // it also for the next call to popElements().
        f = e;
        if (f < intEnd)
            // Forwards
            f++;
        else if (f > intEnd)
            // Backwards
            f--;

        // Do the first animation.
        $("#" + strElID + e.toString()).animate(
             objTo,
            intDuration,
            strEasing,
            // Last animation
                function() {
                $("#" + strElID + e.toString()).animate(
                    objFrom,
                    intDuration,
                    strEasing
                );
            }
        );

        // The last element has been animated..
        if (e == intEnd)
            return;

        // Next element, we're passine the value of f here which should
        // point to the next element to be animated
        setTimeout(function() {
            popElements(
                strElID,
                f,
                intEnd,
                objTo,
                objFrom, 
                intDuration,
                strEasing,
                intTimeout
            );
        }, intTimeout);
    });
}
```

The important thing is to  number the id's in such a way so as they're easy to reference in a loop. I can post the actual code I have if you think it will help, but it's quite specific to my project it might not help but it's just an idea of how you could  make this work.

It's a nice effect and works quite well.

If you put the above <p></p> tags in a file and call:

```
    popElements(
        "char-",
        0,
        10,
        { "opacity": '0.01' },
        { "opacity": '0.99' },
        500,
        "linear",
        100
    );
```

It will apply the animations to each character individually.

Natually, it goes without saying that you don't need to use animate(), you can do whatever you want. Maybe even adapt the function so that it accepts a callback parameter, world's your oyster but I hope it's helpful in sme way.